# React Native Dynamic module with native app gives "couldn't find DSO to load: libjsc.so"

Tags: android, react-native, native

We are trying to load a module dynamically that contains all the react-native related files. but unfortunately, we are getting the below error

[image]

We searched a lot but couldn't find the proper fix for that.  we are initializing the SOLOADER inside the dynamic module.

Current Structure of our Projects:

Android

rnmodule ( which contains all the reactnative related code) , app module is being injected in this module as a structure of dynamic module

appmodule(base) ->

Build.gradle(app)
content->

```
`
if (enableHermes) {
        // for RN 0.61+:
        def hermesPath = "path";

        debugApi files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseApi files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        api jscFlavor
    }


`




project.ext.react = [

    // your index js if not default, other settings
    // Hermes JSC ?
    entryFile    : "index.js",
    root         : "./../",
    enableVmCleanup : false,
    bundleInDebug: false,
    bundleInRelease: false,
    enableHermes : true,
    hermesCommand: "./../path/hermesc",

]

    def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+
    
    def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", true);
    
    '
```

So current issue is whenever we try to launch the React Native Activity it throws the above error.

Couple of things we tried out ->

1. we tried to load the library before actually using the library
   The synatx I used:

   `SplitInstallHelper.loadLibrary(context, "SoLoader")`

-> Not sure if this is really required

2. Tried to enabling/disabling Hermes ( didn't make a difference)
3. Tried to move the above block of code to a specific build.gradle (rn) (None of them seems to resolve this issue)

Goal -> To load the whole module as a dynamic feature

Would be great if somebody can answer these questions along with

1. Do we need to load the library dynamically for a dynamic module  ( According to me it's only required if not being injected in-app )

Comment: did you find solution for this?

Comment: No , we tried couple of things but so far no luck :(

Comment: this errror happened to me because of realm version. If you are using realm. I downgrade version to "realm": "^10.20.0-beta.3". and it worked maybe works for you too.